call blocker.proceed() after submit form to redirect not working- useBlocker() hook
I am using a stepper with four stages and needed to block the browser's back button, which is functioning correctly.
Parent component
 const CreateSpace = ({}) => {

     const blocker = useBlocker(
            ({ currentLocation, nextLocation }) =>
              formData.projectName !== '' &&
              currentLocation.pathname !== nextLocation.pathname
          );
 return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Modal
          className="error-message-modal"
          isOpen={blocker?.state === 'blocked'}
        >
          <ModalBody className="p-3 text-center">
            <h4>{promptMessage}</h4>
          </ModalBody>
          <div className="text-center mb-2 d-flex justify-content-center">
            <Button color="secondary" onClick={() => blocker?.reset()}>
              <IntlMessages id="cai.cancel-label" />
            </Button>
            <Button
              color="secondary btn-multiple-state"
              onClick={() => blocker?.proceed()}
            >
              <IntlMessages id="cai.add-cart-label" />
            </Button>
          </div>
        </Modal>
      </div>

      <Stepper
        steps={[
          { label: 'Overview' },
          { label: 'Services' },
          { label: 'Create permission group' },
          { label: 'Review' },
        ]}
        activeStep={activeStep}
        styleConfig={stepStyleConfig}
      />
      {activeStep === constants.STEP_REVIEW ? (
        
         <Review    <--- child component
          blocker={blocker} <--- passing blocker as prop
        />
      ) : (
        ''
      )}  
      )}
    </>
  );
};

passing the blocker to child component as prop
child component
Now, the submit button is placed in the final step of the stepper. When clicked, the API will be triggered, and upon receiving the response, the user will be redirected to the dashboard page.
    const ReviewStep = (props) => {
           const {blocker, response } = props;
           const navigate = useNavigate();

           const submitFormData = () => {
                 if (Object.keys(formData).length > 0) {
                    dispatch(postSolutionSpace(formData));
                  }
                  if (response && blocker.state === 'blocked') {
                  blocker?.reset?.();  <--- blocker Reset not working
                  navigate(`${adminRoot}solution-space/dashboard`);
                  blocker?.proceed?.();<--- blocker proceed not working
                }
        }
     /* form start*/
        }

in console log i can see unblocked state, but navigation not happening.

I'm not familiar with useBlocker  but your code says that if the blocker's state is blocked, blocker should proceed, so it doesn't block. Isn't?

yes, it should unblock, but not happening so.

Maybe that's because that the check of the blocker state happens after the navigation has been called so at the moment of the navigation, the blocker is still blocked. May I ask what's the scenario? If, at some point you want the blocker to stop blocking, maybe you can all blocker.reset

There's apparently more to this than what you have shared and shown. Where does the blocker unblock the navigation? Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with.

edited and added more details to question.

After lot of struggles i found the bug in my code, the condition inside useBlocker() in parent component is executing every time when navigation requested, thus preventing navigation after submit click, so created a flag to know when submit button click and avoid blocking navigation.

Answer to my question.
Parent component
const [leavePage, setLeavePage] = useState(false);

 const blocker = useBlocker(({ currentLocation, nextLocation }) =>
              !leavePage && formData.projectName !== '' &&
              currentLocation.pathname !== nextLocation.pathname
          );

  /* unblock navigation when form submit */
  useEffect(() => {
      if (blocker.state === 'blocked' && leavePage) {
        blocker?.proceed?.(); /* be care full accessing proceed(), always use inside guard claus */
      }
  }, [blocker,leavePage]);

Child Component
const ReviewStep = (props) => {
           const {blocker, response } = props;
           const navigate = useNavigate();

           const submitFormData = () => {
                 if (Object.keys(formData).length > 0) {
                    dispatch(postSolutionSpace(formData));
                     setLeavePage(true); <-- set flag true on form submit
                  }
                    navigate(`/solution-space/dashboard`);     
             }
            /* form start*/
        }

